# Combine Browsersync with AJAX Request

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

Can use Browsersync to call only once a backend server?

Currently I have a web application that displays a graph online of statistics, that it does is make calls every 1 second to backend for AJAX request.
The problem is that every time the web application opens, multiply calls to the backend is produce.

I would like to call only once at the backend, and update in all client who have opened a connection in the web application.

Looking at the documentation Browsersync I see do that, but only for static pages. Nowhere do I see where to use it to combine with called Ajax that refresh the DOM automatically depending on the response of Ajax.

Thanks in advance for your help.